# white space separated colon key value pairs string to map

Tags: go

I have an output as follows:

```
scope -> profile_id:ed829e455a3db779 result:all
```

I wish to split this into a key value map:

such that `m["profile_id"].(string)` would give me the value `ed829e455a3db779`

Comment: Unless this is a standard format with a decoder, you will need to write code to parse the string. What have you tried so far?  Is this a standard format of some sort?

Comment: Yeah thats what it came down to was hoping there would be something out of the box

Answer (score -2):

For those seeking the same info:

```
scopes := newToken.Extra("scope").(string)
entries := strings.Split(scopes, " ")
m := make(map[string]string)
for _, e := range entries {
    parts := strings.Split(e, ":")
    m[parts[0]] = parts[1]
}
profileID := m["profile_id"]
```

Comment: What is `newToken`?   This looks like important information missing from the question.  The question wants an interface map value, but this answer uses a string map value.  Update the question or answer to match.